# Re-associating an object with its class after deserialization in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, class, serialization

I'm writing a simple serialization / deserialization framework for some application-specific objects.

Consider the following:

```
"use strict";
function Dog(name) { this._name = name; };
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.getName = function() { return this._name; }

var d1 = new Dog('fido');
var d2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d1));  // serialize / deserialize

> d1
Dog { _name: 'fido' }
> d1.getName()
'fido'
> d2
{ _name: 'fido' }
> d2.getName()
TypeError: d2.getName is not a function
```

At this point, one can ask "What does `d1` have that `d2` lacks?"

One approach that partially works is to manually assign the methods of d1 to d2:

```
> d2.constructor = d1.constructor
> d2.getName = d1.getName
> d2.getName()
'fido'
```

This has a couple of disadvantages. First, I have to manually assign each method of d1 to d2.  Second, d2 gets its own properties, and doesn't share slots using the prototype mechanism:

```
> d2
Dog {
   _name: 'fido',
  constructor: [Function: Dog],
  getName: [Function] }
```

So my refined question is: given an object (e.g. `d2`), is there a way to associate it with the prototype of another object (e.g. `d1`) so it inherits the same behavior?

Comment: Meta comment: though this appears to be a duplicate question, the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039534/deserialize-json-to-javascript-object isn't ideal for the node.js environment.  The answer given here is *much* better.  So is it still a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, it is still a duplicate. The answers given here could just as well be moved to the other question.

Comment: @Louis But if this question is better, then that question should be closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: I looked at both question, and did not think that this question is *significantly* better than the other.

Comment: @Louis But the answer here is definitely better. The answer in the other question doesn't work in Node.js. And it doesn't work in some cases, like [this](https://jsbin.com/yebihutozu/1/edit?js,console). Also, these two questions are slightly different - in this OP has a reference to the class, and in the other OP has only the name of the class as a string.

Comment: @Gothdo The difference you point out between the two questions is immaterial. Whatever is going to work to solve the other question is necessarily going to work here too. Your answer is better yes, but that's not the only factor to be considered. The relative age of the questions is also a factor. It is true that we don't just close the newer questions just *because they are newer* but age is not to be ignored either. I've weighed all the factors. I'm not going to *ignore the history of a 4 year-old question* when a duplicate that is not even one day old gets posted.

Comment: I won't belabor the fact that this answer is MUCH better for a node.js environment.  But I've made a notation that this is specifically for node.js and voted to re-open the question.

Comment: @fearless_fool The other question is opened to answers in any and all JS environments. Your question here is a subset of the other by targeting Node.js. We really do not need to have a plethora of questions about how to do this in Node, Chorme, Firefox, Rhino, JS-environment-du-jour.

Comment: @louis: I know you looked at both answers, but you do understand that the other solution simply doesn't work in node.js, right?  (e.g. `var obj = new window[name]();`)

Comment: @fearless_fool What the answer there is doing is that instead of hardcoding class like in Gothdo's answer, there's a lookup done in the global scope. In a browser the global scope is  `window`, in Node that's `global`, and in a Worker that's `self`. In an actual implementation, I'd replace all that with a lookup in an ad-hoc map, which would work anywhere. The `window` thing is really not essential to that answer.

Comment: Louis: I owe you an apology.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039534/deserialize-json-to-javascript-object clearly does something important that @Gothdo's given here doesn't, namely allow you to dynamically choose the containing class.  See my update in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38922992/558639 for  what I think is the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) is what you need.

```
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d1))
const d3 = Object.create(Dog.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj))
```

The difference between this and OP's method is that this method sets `prototype` properties on the prototype, whereas OP's method sets properties directly on the object. You can see this when you loop through object own properties using for-in loop with `hasOwnProperty()` method:

```
for (const i in d1) {
  if (d3.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

With my method it outputs only `_name`, but with OP's method it outputs also `getName`.

Unfortunately, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` is part of ECMAScript 2017 and it's supported only in Firefox for now, so you'll need to use Babel.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). It has better browser support than `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`, but it's discouraged by MDN, because it's slow.

```
const d3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d1))
Object.setPrototypeOf(d3, Dog.prototype)
```

Comment: Clear answer - thanks.  If Object.setPrototypeOf() is too slow, then it should be simple to polyfill getOwnPropertyDescriptors if unavailable.  Thank you for the direction...

Comment: can't thank you enough. This answer works well even on nested classes. However, just curious how does it reference the internal classes?

Answer (score 3):

As I was writing this, I had the idea of creating a custom constructor that uses the deserialized JSON to initialize the object:

```
Dog.createFromJSON = function(obj) {
  var d = new Dog();
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    d[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return d;
}

> d3 = Dog.createFromJSON(JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(d1)))
> d3
Dog { _name: 'fido' }
> d3.getName()
'fido'
```

#### Update: how to dynamically find the class and assign the prototype

As @Louis points out, @Gothdo's answer requires that you know what class the deserialized object belongs to. If you're willing to add the class name to the serialized object, you can use that to determine the class dynamically. So, for example, to expand on the OP's example:

```
> var d1 = new Dog('fido');
> d1['_class'] = 'Dog';
> let jsonString = JSON.stringify(d1)
'{"_name":"fido","_class":"Dog"}'
```

Using the trick described in [deserialize JSON to JAVASCRIPT object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039534/deserialize-json-to-javascript-object) (but tweaked for Node.js) you can use a string to get a handle to a class prototype via Node.js's `global` object:

```
> global[d1['_class']].prototype
Dog { getName: [Function] }
```

Now you can use that to dynamically reconstruct the object using @Gothdo's technique. Putting it all together:

```
/**
 * Dynamically create an object from a JSON string of properties.
 * Assumes the presence of a _class meta-property that names the
 * resulting class.
 */
function reconstitute(jsonString) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    let cls = global[obj['_class']];
    delete obj['_class'];  // remove meta-property
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, cls.prototype);
}

> reconstitute('{"_name":"fido","_class":"Dog"}')
Dog { _name: 'fido' }
```

Comment: So, reading your comments and your answers, my old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039534/deserialize-json-to-javascript-object can't be marked as duplicated, first because it made 5 years before than this question, and because both are described in different scenarios.

Comment: `global[d1['_class']].prototype` gives access (by design) to everything. Only use this to deserialize trusted input, or add a filter on `_class` to only permit deserialization of expected classes

Answer (score 1):

The Best method so far would be:

```
let obj = Object.assign(new ClassyObject(), JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(the_obj_that_will_lost_prototype)))
```

Just improved and more direct:

```
let obj = Object.assign(new the_obj_that_will_lost_prototype.constructor(), JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(the_obj_that_will_lost_prototype)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Method: Change Class In-Place**

If you really need to change the class of an object *in-place*, this function will work on any system that has `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf` defined:

```js
    // set class of object to `name`
    function setObjectClassName(obj, name) {
      let newObj = eval('new ' + name + '()');
      let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(newObj);
      Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, proto);
      return obj;
    }
```

Example using `JSON.serialize()` and `JSON.parse()`:

```js
    class MyClass extends Object {}
    let original = new MyClass();
    original.foo = "bar";

    console.log(original.constructor.name, original);
    //  MyClass { "foo": 'bar' }

    let originalClassName = original.constructor.name;

    let serialized = JSON.stringify(original);
    console.log(serialized.constructor.name, serialized);
    // String '{"foo":"bar"}'

    let restored = JSON.parse(serialized);
    console.log(restored.constructor.name, restored);
    // Object { foo: 'bar' }

    restored = setObjectClassName(restored, originalClassName);
    console.log(restored.constructor.name, restored);
    // MyClass { foo: 'bar' }
```

**Better Method: Copy the Object**

**Mozilla** warns against changing the prototype of an existing object, as it is:

> a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine
>   - [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

If you don't absolutely need to change in-place, this function will copy an object and change the class of the copy:

```js
  function copyObjectAndChangeClass(obj, name) {
    let newObj = eval('new ' + name + '()');
    Object.assign(newObj, obj);
    return newObj;
  }
```

Comment: That `eval` is a huge security hole if the input is not from a trusted source.