# Javascript: Convert an array of strongly typed to JSON

Tags: javascript

I have an array of a class A. Class A contains 2 properties as Weight and Date.

```
var array = [
              A{Weight: 50, Date: 01/01/2009}, 
              A{Weight: 55, Date: 01/02/2009}, 
              A{Weight: 60, Date: 01/03/2009},... 
]
```

How can I convert the above array to something like this:

```
var array = [
              {Weight: 50, Date: 01/01/2009}, 
              {Weight: 55, Date: 01/02/2009}, 
              {Weight: 60, Date: 01/03/2009},... 
]
```

Comment: I do not see any difference between the two array except an extra `A`

Comment: You might start wth valid javascript.

Comment: Not value JS.!!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201589/serializing-an-es6-class-object-as-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code  **isn't valid** `JavaScript` code. I did a little restructuring and here you have one way of achieving what you need, meaning it can be done in different ways, but since your code is not valid, I was restricted. I suggest going over official documentation. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is a great starting point. I also recommend [this](https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html) article.
Anyways, I hope this helps you **;)**

```js
// A valid JS array would look something like this:

const array = [
               {a: {Weight: 50, Date: '01/01/2009'}}, 
               {a: {Weight: 50, Date: '01/01/2009'}}, 
               {a: {Weight: 50, Date: '01/01/2009'}}
];

// Here we define our new array that's going to contain our 'mutated' data

let newArr = [];

// Here we're going over our original array and push redefined data to our 'newArr'

array.map(x => {
  newArr.push(x.a);
});

// Now, let's see how that looks like :)

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Most would write it as `let newArr = array.map(o => o.a)` and save some keystrokes. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I know **:)** I deliberately did it like this to show a little more detail about the process