# how to dynamically add value to object in an array of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I add value to object in an array of objects in Typescript?

Say I have an array of object like this:

```
[{name:'John',age:20}, {name:'Sam',age:26}, {name:'Will',age:2}]
```

What I want is dynamically generated property in each object of array as this:

```
[{name:'John',age:20, value:'John 20'}, {name:'Sam',age:26, value:'Sam 26' }, {name:'Will',age:2, value:'Will 2'}]
```

**This is what I tried:** I have a created a model for type checking and created a method in it which will return the value.

```
export class Names {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    constructor() {
    }
    getConcat() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.age;
    }
}
```

Although when I get data from server of type `Names[]`, I am not able to fetch the dynamically generated value. I am trying to get values like this:

```
this.somevariable:Names[]=[];  //declarartion
this.somevariable[0].getConcat() // inside a method after api call
```

How do I do that? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you `new Names()` and assign values, you don't have an object with the `getConcat` function.

Comment: Show how you are populating `this.somevariable`. If you're getting the data from a server, it's not actually a `Names` object.

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/q/45404571/1915893

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm assigning that somevariable to the response from service which is again of type Names[]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-associating an object with its class after deserialization in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922990/re-associating-an-object-with-its-class-after-deserialization-in-node-js)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript pretty sure this will solve your problem

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR that's not the issue

Comment: It's *declared* as `Names[]`, but it's actually a JavaScript object that merely has the same properties, not methods.

Answer (score 2):

as you made the class for the purpose of typechecking - I'm guessing you mixed up javascript's `class` and typescript's `interface`:

an `interface` is only present during development, and gone in your actual production app.
a `class` is a living js object that is compiled into a functioning object in your app.

an interface for typechecking may look like this:

```
interface Name {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  getConcat: () => string; // hints about the presence of a function that returns a string, within the typed object - but is not a function by itself!
}
```

while a class requires a bit modification

```
export class Names {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number) { // pass arguments to initialize the class object
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }

    getConcat() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.age;
    }
}
```

using `interfaces`, you could say that the array of names you have is of type `Name[]`, meaning:

```
function getConcat () {
   return this.name + ' ' + this.age
}

const names: Name[] = [{name: 'a', age: 1, getConcat: getConcat }, {name: 'b', age: 2, getConcat: getConcat },...];
```

and throughout your code development, you will be hinted about the already preset `getConcat` method, and be warned if it is not there now, or in future.

But in order to use the class for both typechecking AND the `getConcat` function, you will have to map each object into a class:

```
const objects = [{name: 'a', age: 1}, {name: 'b', age: 2}];
const names: Name[] = objects.map(obj => new Name(obj.name, obj.age));
```

And now you can access any method you declared within `Name` class, for each item in `names` array.

You can actually mix the two up, initializing the js classes as shown above, while typechecking the `class` itself:

```
export class Name implements NameInterface {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number) { 
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }

    getConcat() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.age;
    }
}
```

And now you will be warned if your `class` object has not implemented any member of the `NameInterface` declared members (say you forgot to add the `getConcat` function within the class).

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert new attribute then you should write like this: `arr[i].value = arr[i].name + ' '+ arr[i].age;`. Once you get data from API store it in an array and then do as shown below to update your array.

Following is working example:

```js
arr = [{name:'John',age:20}, {name:'Sam',age:26}, {name:'Will',age:2}];

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i].value = arr[i].name + ' '+ arr[i].age;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You don't seem to have read the question. This deals with the title but the content of the question deals with something very different. See the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505493/1915893

Answer (score -1):

```js
arr = [{name:'John',age:20}, {name:'Sam',age:26}, {name:'Will',age:2}];



const generateValue = (items) => {
  return items.map(x=> {
    return {...x, value: `${x.name} ${x.age}`};
  });
};

arr = generateValue(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

You can create function like this