# How to serialize an object and cast it back to the same class as the original object

Tags: javascript, stringify, ecmascript-2017

I'm new to JavaScript so bear with me if what I'm asking is not "how you do it in JavaScript". Advice on other approaches are welcome.

I have a class named `State` and I need need to serialize objects of that class using `JSON.stringify()`. The next step is to deserialize them back into an objects. However, my class uses setters and getters.

The problem that I'm facing is that after I deserialized those objects the setters and getters seem to be gone. I just cannot figure out how I can properly turn serialized objects back into objects of that class so that they behave exactly the same as objects that are created using `new` directly.

In another language I would cast those objects into `State` objects. I cannot find a JavaScript mechanism that seems to work that way.

The code looks as follows:

```
class State {
  constructor(href) {
    this.url = href;
  }

  set url(href) {
    this._url      = new URL(href);
    this.demoParam = this._url.searchParams.get("demoParam");
  }

  get url() {
    return this._url;
  }

  set demoParam(value) {
    let param = parseInt(value, 10);
    if(isNaN(param)) {
      param = 2;
    }
    console.log("Setting 'demoParam' to value " + param);
    this._demoParam = param;
  }

  get demoParam() {
    return this._demoParam;
  }

  toJSON() {
    let stateObject  = {};
    const prototypes = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    for(const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototypes)) {
      const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototypes, key);
      if(descriptor && typeof descriptor.get === 'function') {
        stateObject[key] = this[key];
      }
    }
    return stateObject;
  }
}

let originalState = new State(window.location.href);

let newState1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalState));
newState1.demoParam = 12;

let newState2 = Object.create(State.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalState))));
newState2.demoParam = 13;

let newState3 = Object.assign(new State(window.location.href), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalState)));
newState3.demoParam = 14;

let newState4 = Object.setPrototypeOf(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalState)), State.prototype);
newState4.demoParam = 15;
```

I would expect that everytime I set the `demoParam` property of a `newStateX` object I'd see a console log message. However. I only see it twice, i.e. for every `new State(window.location.href)` statement.

I have used the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38923458) question. However, it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you serialize an object you trigger the `toString` or the `toJSON` method of your class' instance and end up with just a "dumb" JSON representation of your enumerable attributes.

if you want to recreate an instance that behaves like it did prior to serialisation, you will need to set an extra key/value pair in your toJSON function like `___internalType: 'state'` and then later use eg. a `switch` statement  to recreate your specific class with the `new MyClass(serializedData)`and passing in your serialised instance. Within the constructor of your class, you set all the attributes you need and voilà, you have your "old" instance again

/edit: to clarify the reason why your console logs aren't showing up is because you are not recreating an instance of your class but just creating a new plain Object.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I was hoping for a mechanism I hadn't discovered yet. From what I've seen so far, JavaScript classes seem to be a questionable and unfinished concept. There is no proper information hiding, inheritance works completely different compared to other languages and my use case isn't covered either. Seems to be a better option to ditch classes altogether for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, inheritance works via the protoype chain which is different than java etc. But also in other languages you need to hydrate your object somehow after you serialized it to a JSON/protobuf/string. information hiding (àla private variables) will be achievable in the future with [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_fields) but you can achieve it now by using closures

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.assign to copy plain object data into an "empty" new instance of the class along the lines of this code:

```
function cast(o) {
   if (!o._cls) return o;
   var _cls = eval(o._cls);
   return Object.assign(new _cls(), o);
}
```

In JavaScript i personally like to avoid using classes for my data objects. TypeScript offers some better opportunities to solve this problem, one of these is TypedJSON:

https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON

Comment: Isn't the result of that the same that I cover with `let newState3 = Object(assign new State(...` above already?